# Spring Boot, cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, repository

Here is the error:
[ERROR] /C:/dev/ecl_ws_java_17/my-projet/src/main/java/com/fja/health/myproject/repositories/AddressRepository.java:[8,8] cannot access org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository

here is my Repository File:

```
package com.fja.health.installmachine.repositories;

import com.fja.health.installmachine.model.Address;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> {

}
```

and here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.fja.ipl.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
    <version>6.19.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.fja.health</groupId>
<artifactId>install-machine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <spring.boot.version>2.7.13</spring.boot.version>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>releases</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>https://vg-s-nexus.dslocal.com/repository/maven-cd-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://vg-s-nexus.dslocal.com/repository/maven-cd-snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1.2184</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.fja.health.installmachine.InstallMachineApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipIfEmpty>true</skipIfEmpty>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/sla.log4j2.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>springconfig/ipl.persistence.datasource.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>spring-config/ipl-frameworks/ipl-persistence-datasource-config*.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>model/**/*.mwe</exclude>
                            <exclude>model/**/*.mwe2</exclude>
                            <exclude>model/**/*.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>test-model/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>log4j2.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/sla.log4j2.xml</exclude>
                    <exclude>model/**/*.mwe</exclude>
                    <exclude>model/**/*.mwe2</exclude>
                    <exclude>model/**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>test-model/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.cyclonedx</groupId>
            <artifactId>cyclonedx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>makeBom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.37.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <java>
                    <importOrder>
                        <file>formatter/im.importorder</file>
                    </importOrder>
                    <eclipse>
                        <file>formatter/install-machine-formatter.xml</file>
                    </eclipse>
                </java>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <!-- ?? needed to ensure that the resulting jar can be run. -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.fornax.toolsupport</groupId>
            <artifactId>fornax-oaw-m2-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- This is the main dependency to make the project spring boot aware -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
```

javax.persistence
    javax.persistence-api
    2.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

org.springframework.data
    spring-data-jpa
    3.1.1

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.139</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- This dependency adds old fashion (SOAP) web services capabilities to spring boot. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Add jUnit 4 VINTAGE compatibility -->
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--   Add testing capabilities to spring boot. -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl.dsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>dsl-generator</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.modelling.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-util</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-foundation</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-util</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-bsf</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.frameworks.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-lib-spring-ws</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-lib-basic-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fja.ipl.lib</groupId>
        <artifactId>ipl-lib-db-txn</artifactId>
        <version>${ipl.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.20.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Open API annotations dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <!-- profile used to reset database; should only be used in combination with oracle or db2 profile -->
    <profile>
        <id>resetdb</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.fja.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ddlprovider-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>resetdb</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>postgres</id>
        <properties>
            <db.config.name>postgres</db.config.name>
            <db.schema.name>public</db.schema.name>
            <db.version.path>3802</db.version.path>
            <!-- does not seem to be used -->
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I am using eclipse Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0).  If this has to do with classpath in eclipse, please be detailed, as I don't know what that means.  Thank you.